PhpStorm is marking variables given by Controller in View as not declared in MCV application
PhpStorm is marking variables given by Controller in View as not declared in Yii2 application. Why? How can I turn off this faulty message of PhpStorm?
return $this->render('resetPassword', [
    'model' => $model
]);


As you can see in upper screenshot, $model will be marked as not declared. That's nonsense in MCV design pattern application...

"Why?" Because the IDE core knows nothing on how and what variables you pass to the view. Another case: you may use the same view from 2 controllers (by mistake or whatnot) and pass different set of vars. Which one will be correct. Such framework-specific info is normally supplied by a framework-specific plugin.

"How can I turn off this faulty message of PhpStorm?" Declare that variable in your view via inline PHPDoc, e.g. /** @var \App\MyModel $model */

Another option (radical one, in case you want to avoid seeing such warnings but do not wish to utilize PHPDoc comments): disable that particular inspection for your view files: make a new custom scope that will include only view files, and use it in that Inspection.
